# In a b/w '50s comic, a man with robot assistants tries to find a kidnapped girl in a totalitarian dystopia run by robots

Tags: story-identification, comics, robots, dystopia

In this black & white comic from the early '50s, there is a dystopia run by robots, a kidnapped damsel, and the hero is scouting around with loyal robots to help him destroy the totalitarian world. The comic may have been a standalone.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is there anything else you can remember about this?  The art style, perhaps, or how the robots were drawn?